# Does PHP array_rand returns unique keys?

Tags: php, arrays

If I call `array_rand($array, 100)` does it avoid selecting the same key multiple times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, within *one* call the return set should be unique.

Comment: No, I meant in the call `array_rand($array, 100)` can I get the same element twice between the 100 selected?

Comment: I was about to point that out.  @KingCrunch's update is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: No, you won't get the same elements (keys) twice and since 5.2.10 the result isn't shuffled anymore.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it does!** Just read the documentation: http://php.net/array_rand

Or better: try by yourself to get it giving you twice the same key.

```
 $ php -a
 php > print_r(array_rand(array(1,2), 2));
 Array
 (
      [0] => 0
      [1] => 1
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

As `array_rand` throws a warning when specifying a number larger than the array-size I assume keys will be unique.