# trying to rand() without repetition

Tags: php, random

well i have a use for rand();
I need to rand from 1 to x amount 4 times and make sure the value will not return.

This is my code corrently:

```
 $Count = 15;
 $secondstage = '';
 $arrayindex = '';
 for($i=1; $i<5; $i++){
    $arrayindex = rand(1,$Count);
    if($secondstage == $arrayindex){
        for($b=1; $arrayindex == $secondstage; $b++){
            $arrayindex = rand(1,$Count);
        }
    }
    $secondstage = $arrayindex;
    echo $secondstage;
    echo '<br>';
 }
```

Am I having some logic mistake here? I thought of maybe using while but for should also work.

Comment: I am still failing to see whats wrong with my code's logic .. i evened tried it with while ... and same thing

Comment: Why not put inside array and use array_unique() ? or use array_rand()

Comment: Thanks everyone i used marc B's solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you want 4 random non-repeating numbers between 1 and 15, inclusive? You're using way too much code for that. A simpler version:

```
$numbers = array();
do {
   $possible = rand(1,15);
   if (!isset($numbers[$possible])) {
      $numbers[$possible] = true;
   }
} while (count($numbers) < 4);
print_r(array_keys($numbers));
```

Comment: 1 to x - not specifically 15.

Comment: Still too much code :-) check out my version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11805502/1329367

Answer (score 1):

I would put the already random numbers in an array:

```
<?php 
$count = 15;
$cArray = array();
for($i=1; $i<5; $i++){
    $rand = rand(1, $count);
    if(in_array($rand, $cArray)){
        $i--;
    } else {
        $cArray[] = $rand;
        echo $rand . "<br>";
    }
   }
?>
```

I checked it, this code works on local server :)

Comment: Great! Then please toggle one of our answers as working, so other people with the same issue can see it has been answered :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = 15;
$values = range(1, $count);
shuffle($values);
$values = array_slice($values, 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (wich will give you an array with random keys of the original array) :

```
<?php

$array = array();
$max = 100;
$numberValuesWanted = 5;

for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
  $array[] = $i;

$randomKeys = array_rand($array, $numberValuesWanted);

print_r($randomKeys);
```

Comment: Has to be non-repeating numbers.

Comment: I think the above can have repeating numbers mate

Comment: array_rand returns repeated keys ? (I can't remember ...)

Comment: Searched a bit and it seems that it does return unique keys => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826428/does-php-array-rand-returns-unique-keys